# How to return PHP response to HTML page using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to learn web applications, here I have my client side using HTML and server is PHP based. 
I have signup from on my client side, which when filled and click submit button is sent to PHP page using jQuery AJAX. 
So, after the form data is sent or POST to PHP page using AJAX, a couple of validations happen like checking username and email, if the validations succeed it should send back a JSON object to my HTML page "SUCCESS", if validation fails "Error".

So, the problem is when I submit the form it is redirecting me to the PHP page instead of displaying the JSON response back on my html.

I was trying to solve this since last week and I filtered stack overflow, youtube and many other sites for a solution, which didn't go well.

Here is the code

**PHP:**

```
<?php include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php" ); 
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
    $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
else
{
    $user = "";
}
?>

<?php
$registration = @$_POST['signup-submit'];

$fname    = @$_POST['fname'];
$lname    = @$_POST['lname'];
$uname    = @$_POST['uname'];
$email    = @$_POST['email'];
$email_repeat = @$_POST['email_repeat'];
$password = @$_POST['password'];

$ucheck_array = array('Username Takne');
$echeck_array = array('Email already used');
$siginup_sucess_array = array('Sucess');

//Sign-Up form validation
if ($registration) {    
$usernamecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$uname' ");
$usernamecount = mysql_num_rows($usernamecheck);
$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' ");
$emailcount = mysql_num_rows($emailcheck);
if ($usernamecount == 0 && $emailcount == 0) {
    $squery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$uname','$fname','$lname','$dob','$location','$email','$password','$date','0','','','','','','no')" ); 
        echo json_encode($siginup_sucess_array);
}       
else {
    if ($usernamecount == 1) {
        echo json_encode($ucheck_array);
    }
    else if ($emailcount == 1) {
        echo json_encode($echeck_array);
    }
}
}
```

**HTML Form:**

```
<form id="register-form" class="animated fadeInRight" action="http://localhost/Exercises/AJAX/df.php" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="D-O-B" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email_repeat" id="email_repeat" placeholder="Confirm Email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group dob">
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date" value="">
    </div>
    <p class="index_p">By creating the account you accept all the <span style="color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Terms & Conditions.</span></p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="btn_signin" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="signup-submit" id="signup-submit"  value="SIGN UP">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="signup-test"></div> //PHP response to be displayed here
```

**JS:**

```
$("#signup-submit").click( function() {
    $.post( $("#register-form").attr("action"),
        $("#register-form :input").serializeArray(), 
            function(signup_data){
                $("#signup-test").html(signup_data);
            });
clearInput();
});

$("#register-form").submit( function() {
    return false;   
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#register-form :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

To be clear I tried `e.preventDefault`, `return false` and many other scripts,
and my PHP and HTML are not in the same folder or directory.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you opened developers console? Are there any errors?

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), you are using `@`, which is the coding equivalent of being infantile "lalalalala can't hear you", and your js code isn't preventing the normal form submission, so even if the ajax stuff was working correctly, you'd never see it since the form submit causes a page reload.

Comment: @MarcB returning false in the submit handler blocks default submit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll change my PHP, but for now can you help me to prevent from form submission.

Comment: @charlietfl: where, there's no redirect in the php code, so the obvious conclusion is that the form's still submitting.

Comment: I did check the console, and I didn't encounter any errors @u_mulder

Comment: Check for errors in console and also make sure code is wrapped in `$(document).ready` or it may be running before elements exist

Comment: @MarcB but that also assumes the events are being bound too

Comment: I tried $(document).ready previously, it didn't help @Charlietfl

Comment: only reason it wouldn't be prevented is if the elements referenced don't exist when code runs or errors are thrown in browser console

Comment: Why do you have events on the form that are triggered separately? You have the form submission handler and then the click of the submit button. Can you not combine them under the submit only ?

Comment: @charletfl: What do you mean by elements referenced don't exist, is it something with PHP ?

Comment: @Rasclatt: I tried events both way's, which didn't work

Comment: You have `$("#signin-test").html(signup_data);` here, but `<div id="signup-test"></div>` here, AKA: Your id's don't match-> `#signIN` vs. `signUP`

Comment: @Rasclatt: I'm sorry, it was a typo when I was updating code on this question. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following script, hope it would help someone.
The problem with all the scripts which I tried is, they don't have **XMLHttpRequest** permission to POST data and get the data back from PHP(server side in my case).

So, **XMLHttpRequest** is a must for Ajax to Get or Post data "CROSS_DOMAIN".

Script :

```
function signup(){
var firstname    = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var lastname     = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var uname        = document.getElementById("uname").value;
var email        = document.getElementById("email").value;
var email_repeat = document.getElementById("email_repeat").value;
var password     = document.getElementById("password").value;

if (fname == "") {
    document.getElementById("fname").style.background = "rgba(244,67,54,0.45)";
    document.getElementById("fnamestatus").innerHTML = "<p style='width: 30px; color: rgba(255, 62, 48, 0.9); font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin-top:5px; margin-left: -40px; margin-bottom: 0px;'>2-25</p>";    
}

else if (email != email_repeat){
    document.getElementById("email").style.background = "rgba(244,67,54,0.45)";
    document.getElementById("email_repeat").style.background = "rgba(244,67,54,0.45)";
    alert("Your email fields do not match");
}

else {
    var signup_ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    signup_ajax.open("POST", "URL which you want to post data", true);
    signup_ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    signup_ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (signup_ajax.readyState == 4 && signup_ajax.status == 200) {
            if (signup_ajax.responseText = "Success"){
                alert("Account created");
            } 
            else if (signup_ajax.responseText = "Try again.") {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                alert("Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
    signup_ajax.send("fname=" +fname+ "&lname=" +lname+ "&uname=" +uname+ "&email=" +email+ "&email_repeat=" +email_repeat+ "&password=" +password );
    } 
 }
```

PHP(I'm just posting the basic php, you can always add as may validations as you need) :

```
if(isset($_POST["uname"])) {

$fname    = @$_POST['firstname'];
$lname    = @$_POST['lastname'];
$uname    = @$_POST['uname'];
$email    = @$_POST['email'];
$email_repeat = @$_POST['email_repeat'];
$password = @$_POST['password'];

//Sign-Up form validation
if($_POST) {
    $squery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$uname','$fname','$lname','$email','$password')" ); 
        echo 'Sucess';
}       
else 
    echo 'Try again.';
}
```

Only change what I did to my **HTML** Form is :

```
<input type="button" name="signup-submit" id="signup-submit" class="form-control btn btn-signup" onclick="signup()" tabindex="4" value="SIGN UP">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more flexible jQuery ajax. I use this version if ajax because I can change it to get and post very easily. I have tested this method and it works with your form:

```
<script>
function clearInput() {
    $("#register-form :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register-form").submit(function(e) {
        //console.log($(this).attr("action"));
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response)
                {
                    // console.log(response);
                    $("#signin-test").html(response);
                    clearInput();
                },
            error: function(response)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the script, but when I enter the form and click submit, the value given to my <input type="submit> value is becoming empty and the form is not submitting, and not giving any response from PHP or giving any error in console, and also not redirecting to php page also.

Comment: Yes, it is working in the link which you posted, but you have everything in a single php file I guess. In my case I have html in a different folder and Php in a different folder. Is that affecting the ajax functionality ?

Comment: Well I have everything in one file for sake of ease, I would just have to change the url in the jquery to point somewhere else and it will work just as well.

Comment: I'm getting the first console.log i.e the url given in the action, but the second one is not displaying anywhere in the console.

Comment: So neither the error or success console returning anything? On both returns do `console.log('success');` and `console.log('error');` (on each corresponding function that is). See if the console comes back with anything.

Comment: I added console.log('sucess') and ('error') after console.log(response) and  console.log($(this).attr("action"); . So now in my console I can see my php url which we gave in action, followed by sucess text, followed by error and the followed by a empty line from console.log(response)

Comment: The console.log(response) given in success is not working, instead the console.log given in error is working, that means the form data is not reaching php page. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I changed 7 and 9 line of Js to $("#signup-submit").click(function(e) { and data: $("#register-form :input").serialize(),
 and now I'm encountering XMLHttpRequest error saying "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Rohan/Desktop/Final/index.html"

Comment: I could probably help you with team viewer but not for at least one hr

Comment: That is great, hope you can fix it in an hour. Can you give me your email id so I can send you my Team viewer details, or hangouts is also fine

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are handling your form based on the behavior of a button. You should be listening for the onSubmit event of the form and preventing that from firing.

```
$("#register-form").submit( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.post( $("#register-form").attr("action"),
        $("#register-form :input").serializeArray(), 
            function(signup_data){
                $("#signup-test").html(signup_data);
            });
clearInput();
});
```

Comment: I used the same script, what is happening with this script is it is prevention the from from submitting i.e the data is not getting posted to my php page and not getting any response back from it

Comment: To be clear my php is on localhost and html files are on my desktop, I placed them that way because I want to use html on client device and PHP as a server, and make ajax calls from client and get or post data to server

Comment: The script I posted is listening for `$("#register-form").submit()`, the one you posted is listening for `$("#signup-submit").click()`. A submit button inside a form will always cause the form to submit. change it to type="button", or handle the form event, instead of the button event.

Comment: I used type=button and the script which you posted, but the form is not submitting yet

Comment: @Shrey you need to do one, or the other lol. Now the code I posted is not working because you changed the button to type=button, so the form is not firing the submit event. Leave the button type=submit and try the code i posted.

Comment: Shouldn't be that complicated, you main problem was that the form was causing the page to reload, just need to prevent the form from submitting. Here's and example: https://jsfiddle.net/8to7dLd6/

Comment: I tried the code, it still is not working in my case